# Trocar de Fragements sem carregar a tela toda

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou com um problema no meus estudos,
quando eu troco de Fragement e depois eu volto para a Fragment de origem os dados são carregados todos de novo.

E como os dados vem da web, leva um tempo e recursos preciosos,
queria uma forma que enquanto o app estivesse aberto as telas já bertas não fossem recarregadas.

na minha onNavigationItemSelected que fica na MainActivity
o código de transição de fragements é o seguinte

```
if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("one") != null) {
                        //if the fragment exists, show it.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("one")).commit();
                    } else {
                        //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, new CategoriaFragment(), "one").commit();

}
```

porém isso só esta evitando que a tela seja recarregada quando clicada no menu que abre  a tela atual.

Minha Activity principal é nela que eu chamo as minhas fragments e controlo a transição entre elas.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String tituloNavBar;
    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private CategoriaFragment mCategoriaFragment;
    private BuscaFragment mBuscaFragment;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    tituloNavBar = getResources().getString(R.string.nav_bar_last);
                    titulo(tituloNavBar);
                    setFragment(mBuscaFragment,"Busca");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    tituloNavBar = getResources().getString(R.string.nav_bar_start);
                    titulo(tituloNavBar);
                    if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("one") != null) {
                        //if the fragment exists, show it.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("one")).commit();
                    } else {
                        //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, new CategoriaFragment(), "one").commit();
                    }

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    tituloNavBar = getResources().getString(R.string.nav_bar_filter);
                    titulo(tituloNavBar);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        tituloNavBar = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        titulo(tituloNavBar);
        if(mBuscaFragment == null)
            mBuscaFragment = new BuscaFragment();


        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        //Fragmente padrão
        setFragment(mBuscaFragment,tituloNavBar);



    }


    //Substituido pela logica acima
    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String name){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_in_left);
            ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
    private void titulo(String titulo){
        setTitle(titulo);

    }

}
```

é uma activity que contem um menu e pode chamar 3 fragments,
da seguinte forma
**Activity principal**

```
         - Fragment de busca
         - Fragment de categoria
         - Fragment de filtro
```

o resultado de qualquer um desses fragments resultaria em uma **nova activity**, seria para mostrar o detalhes, e essa activity teria mais 3 fragments.

Comment: Como você está implementando sua tela principal? Por que, dependendo de sua aplicação, vai ser necessário uma verificação ´para atualizar o layout. Explique melhor como é essa sua aplicação, por favor.

Comment: @lucas_marciano adicionei uma explicação no final

Comment: Danilo, no seu fragment você está carregando os dados no onResumo ou no onCreate?

Comment: Tudo no onCreate, me recomenda uma forma melhor?

Comment: Amigo o seu problema todo esta no ciclo de vida do fragment, te indico a ver esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7uVghlmWaM). Pelo que eu to entendo do seu problema, vc carrega todo seu layout no onCreat(), e é indicado utilizar o onResume para evitar que se carregue o fragment sem necessidade, também vi que você usa o .add ao invés do replace, veja esse vídeo e de uma estudada na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Obrigado, com o vídeo eu conseguir fazer minha fragment não ser destruída ao rotacionar o aparelho, mas não mantinha a fragement quando era feita a troca de fragement, mas com o código abaixo eu cheguei a solução.

Obrigado, pois eu também queria manter minha fragment na rotação também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguir solucionar meu problema, na Activity eu usei esse código para chamar as Fragments

```
if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(BuscaFragment.KEY) != null) {
                        //if the fragment exists, show it.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ConcursoFragment.KEY)).commit();
                    } else {
                        //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, new ConcursoFragment(), ConcursoFragment.KEY).commit();

                    }
                        if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(CategoriaFragment.KEY) != null){
                        //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(CategoriaFragment.KEY)).commit();
}
```

na logica

```
if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(CategoriaFragment.KEY) != null)
```

aqui ele verifica se a ultima fragmente não é nula, se ela não for nula em vez de destruir ele só oculta, assim para próxima vez ele usa o show em vez do add no condicional acima
se alguém tiver uma solução melhor do que essa, por favor compartilhe